# Change sort order with Sitecore Restful API

Tags: api

Can sortorder of a sitecore item be change or set during a Create or Edit through the Sitecore Restfull API. It seems you can only read standard fields?

Sitecore Version 9.3

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the string approach written in the sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html when sending the data for the item creation, for example:

```
xhr.send("{\n \"ItemName\": \"Home\", \n \"TemplateID\": \"76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa\",
\n    \"Title\": \"Sitecore\" \n}");
```

you can use this approach instead to set the sortorder during Create Item:

```
  var obj = {};
  obj['ItemName'] = "Home";
  obj['TemplateID'] = "76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa";
  obj['__Sortorder'] = "you custom sort order value";
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
```

Same approach can be used when editing an item, you can set other standard fields as long as you set the correct field names, for example `obj['__Final Renderings']`